# How to create a pandas pivot df aggregating on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have this dataframe

```
    date    sym vals
0   2000-01-03  A   1
1   2000-01-04  A   1
2   2000-01-04  A   1
3   2000-01-04  B   2
4   2000-01-04  B   2
5   2000-01-05  B   2
6   2000-01-05  C   3
7   2000-01-05  C   3
8   2000-01-05  C   3
```

I would like a pivot df that looks like this :

```
sym 2000-01-03  2000-01-04  2000-01-05
A   1.0          1.0         NaN
B   NaN          2.0         2.0
C   NaN          NaN         3.0
```

However my code below generates something like this :

```
date sym    2000-01-03  2000-01-04  2000-01-05
0    A        1.0        1.0         NaN
1    B        NaN        2.0         2.0
2    C        NaN        NaN         3.0
```

This is my code to create df and pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-04",
                         "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-05"],
                   "sym": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B", "C", "C", "C"],
                   "vals": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
                  })
```

```
df_pivot = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                         values='vals',  
                         index=[ 'sym'], 
                         columns=['date'],
                         aggfunc=np.mean )
          .reset_index()
         )
df_pivot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `rename_axis` rather than `reset_index`

```
out = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                         values='vals',  
                         index=[ 'sym'], 
                         columns=['date'],
                         aggfunc=np.mean ).rename_axis(None,axis=1)
          
         )
     2000-01-03  2000-01-04  2000-01-05
sym                                    
A           1.0         1.0         NaN
B           NaN         2.0         2.0
C           NaN         NaN         3.0
```